# My car was recalling but my car is already more than 10 years old. Repair free?

Tags: repair, safety

I just found out that my car was recalling after read the news.  My dealer never told that my car was recalling. My car was recalling last year.

I was doing some research and found out that most dealer most likely won't repair my car for free if my car was more than 10 years old from the purchased date.  I bought my car at 2004.

I am wondering if anyone you successfully get your car repair after recalling although your car is more than 10 years old?